# meaning of "balance" and "exclusivity"

Tags: word-meaning

> To *balance* this abbreviated pathway for development and approval of biosimilar and interchaneable products with incentives to develop innoative new products, the BPCI Act also provides **exclusivity** to manufacturers of certain biological products. [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm613761.pdf)

Hi again, I have two questions, and since they are in one sentence, I would like to post it once. If I cannot, please let me know.

1. In this sentence, does balance mean the following definition?

   > [transitive] to create or preserve a good or correct balance between different features or aspects [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/balance_2)
2. Does exclusivity mean the right to monopolize here?
   When I looked for the word, it only says

   > the state of being the only person, group of people, or organization that is allowed to have or do somethin [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exclusivity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes the FDA intends to offer incentives/rewards to these companies in exchange for them bringing innovation to the market i.e. lower drug costs. The worry is that these companies will reap the rewards, yet provide little/no innovation.
2. Yes that is one of the rewards. There is BIG money in patenting novel and useful drugs, and an exclusivity arrangement (whilst not lasting as long as a patent) is a very juicy prize. Eventually, the exclusivity rights will end and the drug will become available for much cheaper from lots of different companies.